# is it possible to convert all columns to varchar(500) in sql server all at time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have some 600 columns in DB.While creating I made int instead of varchar.So in order to make all the columns to varchar(500) do i have to write alter command 576 times or is there any way to convert all to varchar(500).I use sql server now

Comment: Are you sure it's wise or necessary to  change everything into a varchar?

Comment: @SWeko totally i have 614 columns and out of that 600 are varchar.So i will first delete columns that are not varchar(if it is possible to alter all) then i will create new non varchar columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query

```
select o.object_id, o.name, c.column_id, c.name
from sys.columns c
  inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id=c.object_id
where c.system_type_id = (select system_type_id from sys.types where name='int')
  and o.type='U'
  and o.name = 'SomeTableName' -- if you want to filter by table
```

will give you all the columns in your database that are defined with an `int` datatype. Massage the select statement to generate the correct `alter` syntax, like this:

```
select 'alter table '+ o.name +' alter column '+ c.name +' varchar(500);'
from sys.columns c
  inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id=c.object_id
where c.system_type_id = (select system_type_id from sys.types where name='int')
  and o.type='U'
  and o.name = 'SomeTableName' -- if you want to filter by table
```

, copy the result into another query editor window, and let it rip.

**Make sure that you are in the correct database before you run it, and do a backup before, as this can destroy your database structure in a moment**

Comment: see i am n number for tables in my DB and i do not want to change all the int columns present in my DB.Just i want to change for a particular table not for all tables

Comment: @javaBeginner added a condition to filter by table

Comment: see my table name status_table.Can you update your answer using this table name

Answer (score 1):

Try following (do backup before):

```
declare @commands table (SqlStatement nvarchar(max))

insert into @commands (SqlStatement)
select 'alter table ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(T.name)
    + ' alter column ' + quotename(c.name) + ' varchar(500)'
from sys.tables T
    join sys.schemas S on S.schema_id = T.schema_id
    join sys.columns c on c.object_id = T.object_id
where c.name = 'ColName' -- specify conditions to identify tour columns
order by S.name, T.name, c.name

declare csSql cursor local fast_forward for
select SqlStatement from @commands

open csSql

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

fetch next from csSql into @sql
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin

    begin try
        print @sql
        --inspect ouput and uncomment exec if you sure
        --exec(@sql)
    end try
    begin catch
        print error_message()
    end catch

    fetch next from csSql into @sql
end

close csSql
deallocate csSql
```

Change condition to identify your columns and uncomment `exec` when you sure output is fine.

Though, **it will not help you for columns participating in PKs, FKs, indexes, check constraints, etc.**